# Get from Android BroadcastReceiver to a UI

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have a receiver that works well, but I can't seem to show a proper UI, although the toast appears correctly. As far as I can tell, this is caused by Android requiring the class to extend Activity, however, the class already extends BroadcastReceiver, so I can't do this.
So, I tried to do an Intent, but this failed too. There are no errors, but the screen doesn't show. Source code is below.

*Broadcast (Method in AndyRoidAlarm)*

```
public void setAlarm(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(AndyRoidAlarm.this, Reciever.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AndyRoidAlarm.this,
                0, intent, 0);

    // We want the alarm to go off 30 seconds from now.
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

    // Schedule the alarm!
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);

    // Tell the user about what we did.
    if (mToast != null) {
        mToast.cancel();
    }
    mToast = Toast.makeText(AndyRoidAlarm.this, "Alarm Scheduled for 30secs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    mToast.show();
}
```

*Reciever*

```
public class Reciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(context, AlarmRing.class);
    }
}
```

*Reciever V2*

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent foo = new Intent(context, AlarmRing.class);
        //foo.putExtra("id", "id");//example, if you wish to pass custom variables
        context.startActivity(foo);
    }
```

*AlarmRing*

```
public class AlarmRing extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alarm);

        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.sweetchild);
        mp.start();
    }
```

*Manifest*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.comaad.andyroidalarm"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".AndyRoidAlarm"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.comaad.andyroidalarm.Reciever" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.comaad.andyroidalarm.Reciever"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name=".AlarmRing"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest> 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `BroadcastReceiver` `onReceive()` method, if you need a `Context` (e.g., to create an `Intent`), use the `Context` that is passed to you as a parameter of `onReceive()`. You even have this code in your `onReceive()` -- you're just not doing anything with the resulting `Intent` (e.g., calling `startActivity()`).

Comment: RecieverV2 above, now just crashes the app when the reciever is called. It seems to want a flag of kinds, but im unsure how to set this up. LogCat: 03-21 23:05:45.573: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(769): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.comaad.andyroidalarm.Reciever: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: Well, starting an activity from a broadcast receiver is an unusual operation. For most apps, popping up an activity unannounced will make the user very angry. An alarm clock app is one of the few that justify it. Follow the instructions in the error message -- add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to the `Intent` you use for `startActivity()` -- and your problem will hopefully go away.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent foo = new Intent(this, AlarmRing.class);
foo.putExtra("id", id);//example, if you wish to pass custom variables
this.startActivity(foo);
```

**Edit**
Check out this example to use BroadcastReciever within an Activity. http://almondmendoza.com/2009/01/04/getting-battery-information-on-android/

Comment: I tried that before, but i get errors on creator: 
The constructor Intent(Reciever, Class<AlarmRing>) is undefined
As far as I can tell, its caused by the Reciever extending BroadcastReciever, not Activity.